# Get Character At in an Batch Parameter?

Tags: command-line, batch

I want to create a command **go** as follows:

```
go foldera\folderb
:: executes
:: cd foldera\folderb
:: dir

go Z:\foldera\folderb
:: executes
:: Z:
:: cd foldera\folderb
:: dir
```

I tried with **just** `cd` and does not seem to work.
For this to work, i want to be able to check the *2nd character* of *path (1st parameter)*, and then compare it to `:`. If so then run an additional command `<1st character>:`, where *1st character* is the *drive letter*.

What would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: A bit unclear what are you asking for. However, in Windows you need not check drive letter; use [`/D` switch: change the current DRIVE in addition to changing folder](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) instead:  `cd /D foldera\folderb` or `cd /D Z:\foldera\folderb`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know that `cd` had such an option. This is what i needed.

Comment: Take a look over here for more batch-file help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file

Comment: i will make sure to search for some help in reference of these commands. thanks.